# Implementing a solution: A Set Of CheckBoxs and TextBox associated to each CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, checkbox, repeater

First of all I'm sorry for the question's title, but I've spent hours trying to figure out something for my problem and I really don't think the title can elaborate the idea that I'm trying to implement so I hope I can deliver the idea here.

Ok, Now I have a page to create a bag .. each bag consists of items and quantity of each item should be specified.

CreateBagPage: I just need to have a set of CheckBoxs and a TextBox associated with each CheckBox.

the CheckBoxes Text property will be the name of the item (driven from my Db table) .. and if I want to add the item to the bag I select the checkbox .. I also have to specify a quantity for each item so that's why I need to associate a TextBox to each CheckBox. there's a little problem too, that made me start thinking about creating a UserControl and put it in a repeater. the problem is that each item has an ID and I need to I save the item through it's ID and there's no available properties in the CheckBox to accept sort of a ValueField or something!

I'm Hope I can find help here..

Comment: Can you please post some code, so that we can better understand your problem and provide you a solution.

Comment: I Really hope I can post any code samples! .. it's just a hazard a lot of commented and non working code :S .. If I got a clean idea I'll post the code right away

Comment: You can only post relevant chunks of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate the hidden field, save the Id in that and then when you access the check and you can get the Id from hidden field

Comment: I thought about that .. but do I put them in a repeater ItemTemplate or do I create a WebUserControl ? .. please samples would be really really helpful

Comment: You can put repeater item template where you have added your checkbox.

Comment: I think my mind is just blocked because I've been working for so many hours .. now I created a repeater and added to it's ItemTemplate a textbox, hiddenfield, checkbox .. the display is going okay. Now I'll try to retrieve the data from the controls in the reapeter.

Comment: Kashef; Personally I would suggest you to, don't work so many hours and on weekend. This way you will be exhaust early from  Development :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Although I don't really do that a lot but I have to meet a deadline and I have no time :S .. and I used the HiddenField and put all my controls in the ItemTemplate and it worked fine .. Thank you =) +1

Answer (score 0):

You could give your TextBoxes and CheckBoxes IDs with suffixes 1..n (like tb_1, cb_1) and when a checkBox is checked, parse the number x out of its ID and find the control with ID tb_x.